# Public class: Makes pointer from integer without cast

Tags: iphone, objective-c, pointers, casting, persistence

I have written a class to help save and load data for the sake of persistence for my iPhone application but I have a problem with some NSUIntegers that I'm passing across.

Basically, I have the code to use pointers, but eventually it has to start out being an actual value right? So I get this error

```
warning: passing argument 1 of 'getSaveWithCampaign:andLevel:' makes pointer from integer without a cast
```

My code is laid out like so.

(Persistence is the name of the class)

```
NSDictionary *saveData = [Persistence getSaveWithCampaign:currentCampaign andLevel:[indexPath row]];
```

Here's Persistence.m

```
#import "Persistence.h"


@implementation Persistence

+ (NSString *)dataFilePath
{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    return [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:kSaveFilename];
}

+ (NSDictionary *)getSaveWithCampaign:(NSUInteger *)campaign andLevel:(NSUInteger *)level
{
    NSString *filePath = [self dataFilePath];

    if([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filePath])
    {
        NSDictionary *saveData = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];

        NSString *campaignAndLevelKey = [self makeCampaign:campaign andLevelKey:level];

        NSDictionary *campaignAndLevelData = [saveData objectForKey:campaignAndLevelKey];

        [saveData release];

        return campaignAndLevelData;
    }
    else
    {
        return nil;
    }

}

+ (NSString *)makeCampaign:(NSUInteger *)campaign andLevelKey:(NSUInteger *)level
{
    return [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d - ", campaign+1] stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", level+1]];
}   

@end
```

Comment: What is the type of `currentCampaign` in the method call?

Comment: Please show us the method in which you are calling `getSaveWithCampaign` in.

Comment: currentCampaign is an NSUInteger and is declared and synthesised.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should get rid of the `*` in `( NSUInteger *)` in the `getSaveWithCampaign` method.

If you read the error message closely, it states that you are making a **pointer** (`*`) from an **integer** without a cast.

Your `getSaveWithCampaign` method should now have the following signature:

```
+ (NSDictionary *)getSaveWithCampaign:(NSUInteger)campaign andLevel:(NSUInteger)level
```

---

If, on the other hand, for some reason you do want to use pointers, you can pass in the `NSUInteger` prefixed with an ampersand (`&`) to pass in the address of the `NSUInteger` in memory.

Comment: I'm really paranoid about memory usage, so I'm trying to use pointers as much as possible. Sounds kind of dumb for such small values. I'm trying the ampersand method, if that works I'll stick with it unless I get some headaches down the road.

Thanks for your concise and prompt reply! Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: As you can imagine, that comment before resulted in a wild goose chase of errors. I simple removed the need for pointers and I'm making progress. I think I was being too over the top with pointers and not really fully understanding how they're meant to be used.

I am getting further.